# about epoll_ctl()

Tags: c, sockets, epoll

when using epoll_ctl(), I found that the third parameter "fd" is another file descriptor besides the epoll file descriptor "epfd". And I saw an example like this:

```
event.data.fd = sfd; //sfd is a fd for listening
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &event);
```

As I saw, file descriptor in event.data.fd is the same as the third parameter in epoll_ctl, why need to pass this descriptor twice? is there any difference?

Comment: You may consider the implementation didn't do the assignment for you. Sometimes low level C system call rely on programmers. The event is not always needed, e.g. during EPOLL_CTL_DEL the event is ignored but you cannot give a NULL pointer as argument.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually you don't **have** to set `event.data.fd`. It's a union, you can set other members. When `epoll_wait` returns you get the `event.data` associated with the descriptor that became interesting:

```
typedef union epoll_data {
    void    *ptr;
    int      fd;
    uint32_t u32;
    uint64_t u64;
} epoll_data_t;
```

Which means you're completely free **not** to put anything in `fd` and put something in `ptr` instead (for example).

In conclusion, `epoll_ctl` can't rely on the fact you'll fill `fd` in, that's why it has a separate explicit parameter.

Comment: The `fd` you pass to `epoll_ctl` is the file descriptor you wish to get events for. The `fd` in `event.data` is strictly for your use -- the system ignores it and you can use it for any purpose.

Comment: I've actually seen a lot of code that puts the fd in the epoll_data structure, only to use that fd as an index into a table that holds a pointer to the application's structure associated with that socket -- a structure that also contains the fd. Apparently, they didn't realize they could use the `ptr` member instead of `fd` and save the lookup.

Comment: OK, I understand --- the fd in epoll_data is not intended to be used by the system but by myself.

Comment: To clarify, the ev that is epoll_ctl(..ADD..) is "spit back out" when you epoll_wait() and there's an event? @DavidSchwartz i.e., can you "store" the pointers in epoll?

Comment: @awelotta You can store whatever is useful to you in that union. Using `ptr` to store a pointer to some object or structure with information about the context is common.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was just wondering if you risked memory leak if you stored malloc'd pointers (i.e. is it sufficient to just make sure you `epoll_wait`'d every epoll fd?)

Comment: @awelotta So long as you `free` them when you are done with them, there's no risk of a leak.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is.

This is my test demo.

When using `ev.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO`

In the terminal, you press the Enter button to end the input and printf “welcome...”

When using `ev.data.ptr = stdin`

You need to press ctrl+d to end the input and printf “welcome...”

Does it mean that ev.data is not only used for recording?

```
    int main()
    {
        int epfd, nfds;
        struct epoll_event ev, events[5];
        epfd = epoll_create(1); 
    
        //ev.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
        ev.data.ptr = stdin;
        ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET; 
        epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &ev); 
    
        for (;;)
        {   
            nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 5, -1);
            for (int i = 0; i < nfds; i++)
            {
                // if (events[i].data.fd == STDIN_FILENO)
                if (events[i].data.ptr == stdin)
                   printf("welcome to epoll's word!\n");
            }
        } 
    }
```