# Why does epoll_ctl need the filedescriptor twice?

Tags: file-descriptor, epoll

In the example:

```
event.events = EPOLLIN;
event.data.fd = fd;

int ret = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, event.data.fd, &event);
```

I pass the file descriptor in as both a member of `event.data` and as an argument in its own right.

What does `epoll_ctl` need the file descriptor twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [about epoll_ctl()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9325748/7401546)

The reason it needs it twice is that `data` inside `event` is a `union`. `epoll_ctl` does not know whether you actually provided a file descriptor or something else.

```c
typedef union epoll_data {
    void        *ptr;
    int          fd;
    uint32_t     u32;
    uint64_t     u64;
} epoll_data_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event)`

Where:

`epfd` is the file descriptor returned by epoll_create which identifies the epoll instance in the kernel.

`fd` is the file descriptor we want to add to the epoll list/interest list.

`op` refers to the operation to be performed on the file descriptor fd. In general, three operations are supported:

- Register fd with the epoll instance (EPOLL_CTL_ADD) and get notified about events that occur on fd
- Delete/deregister fd from the epoll instance. This would mean that the process would no longer get any notifications about events on that file descriptor (EPOLL_CTL_DEL). If a file descriptor has been added to multiple epoll instances, then closing it will remove it from all of the epoll interest lists to which it was added.
- Modify the events fd is monitoring (EPOLL_CTL_MOD)

`event` is a pointer to a structure called epoll_event which stores the event we actually want to monitor fd for.

The first field events of the `epoll_event` structure is a bitmask that indicates which events fd is being monitored for.

Like so, if fd is a socket, we might want to monitor it for the arrival of new data on the socket buffer (EPOLLIN). We might also want to monitor fd for edge-triggered notifications which is done by OR-ing EPOLLET with EPOLLIN. We might also want to monitor fd for the occurrence of a registered event but only once and stop monitoring fd for subsequent occurrences of that event. This can be accomplished by OR-ing the other flags (EPOLLET, EPOLLIN) we want to set for descriptor fd with the flag for only-once notification delivery EPOLLONESHOT. All possible flags can be found in the man page.

The second field of the epoll_event struct is a union field.

[Source](https://medium.com/@copyconstruct/the-method-to-epolls-madness-d9d2d6378642)

Added some extra data apart from just what was asked for context.

Hope this helps!